# Fetching data from a third party through a VPN tunnel

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, virtual-machine, vpn

I am working on building a data pipeline that fetches data from a third party's relational database and dump it to s3 or local hdfs.

To get to their database, we need to go though a VPN tunnel. VPN client I'm using is fortinet_ssl_vpn client. Once I'm connected to the VPN I can use `sqoop` to import the data. I'm developing this pipeline on an ubuntu virtual machine.

Problem I am facing is once I make the VPN connection on VM, the ssh terminal gets stuck and I'm not able to ssh into that VM from another terminal window as well.

Command I'm using for making VPN connection is below:

```
./forticlientsslvpn_cli --server <host>:<port> --vpnuser <user> --keepalive
```

I am not able to figure out what is causing this behaviour, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you prompted to enter the password?

Comment: My understanding is after setting up VPN, you cannot ssh to remote host.

If so, can you please do some tests:

1. make sure the remote host is reachable, in case VPN route wrong, I mean ping remote host IP to make sure remote host is accessible

2. telnet remote_ip 22 to make sure TCP level is OK

3. If 22 port is accessible, try to ssh -v username@remote_ip to see which step stuck

4. Try to ping -s 9000 remote IP to test jumbo packets can go through the circuit.

Answer (score 0):

One reason can be that the server wants a username and password. [Expect](https://linux.die.net/man/1/expect) can help with that problem.

```
expect "Password for VPN:"
send -- "password\r"
expect "Would you like to connect to this server? (Y/N)"
send -- "Y\r"
expect eof
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I'm providing it the username and password, same way you suggested. Establishing the VPN connection is not the issue, once the connection is made, I can't ssh into it.

Comment: Then it might be because your gateway is changed. This can break SSH, use hosts file or iptables to fix.